# jQuery .val() Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

When I test script below in IE, after click on `input` the cursor moves to the begining of the input.

```
[texttext{I click here}ext  ] -->  [{cursor goes here after click}texttextxt  ] 

$(".chrome-input").focus(function (){
   $(this).val("test");
});
```

Comment: Not quite following. I'd suggest using jsfiddle.net to make this problem available so everyone can see the issue you are seeing and then post the link to that jsfiddle.net example.  It's much easier for everyone.

Comment: I'm gonna assume `.chrome-input` are `<input type="text" />` and that the cursor you are referring to is not the mouse cursor but the text input cursor... That being said, when you click the input you change the text and the cursor moves to the back of the input ?

Comment: Probably because you're changing the text...where *should* it put the cursor? And anyway, just explicitly set its position afterward..there are some plugins for that.

Comment: Khez yes, it moves to the begining of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will set the cursor to the end after input gets focus.

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).val('test');
    window.o = this;
    if (o.setSelectionRange) /* DOM */
    setTimeout('o.setSelectionRange(o.value.length,o.value.length)', 2);
    else if (o.createTextRange) /* IE */
    {
        var r = o.createTextRange();
        r.moveStart('character', o.value.length);
        r.select();
    }
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/pevtN/2/