# Cursor wrong placement in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Would you please try the following in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
* { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 96%; }
label { width: 10em; float: left; }
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
p { clear: both; }
.submit { margin-left: 12em; }
em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("#curl").focus(function(){
    if( this.value == this.defaultValue ) {
        $(this).val("http://");
    }
});
    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
   <p>
     <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" value="Name" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" value="Email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="URL" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required">Comment</textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see the cursor goes back to the beginning of the field if you focus on the URL field. It works with no problem in other browsers. How can it be corrected?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the same problem as here:

[jQuery .val() Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546602/jquery-val-internet-explorer)